# JavaScript array of pointers like in C++

Tags: javascript, arrays, pointers, object

I'm faced with a situation in JavaScript when I need to update an object via its pointer similar to С++ array of pointers to objects
Example code for my issue:

```js
var foo = new Array();
var bar = function(){ 
    this.test = 1;
    foo.push(this); // push an object (or a copy of object?) but not pointer
};
var barInst = new bar(); // create new instance
// foo[0].test equals 1
barInst.test = 2;
// now barInst.test equals 2 but
// foo[0].test still equals 1 but 2 is needed
```

So, how can I solve this? Should I use a callback or something like this or there is an easy way to help me to avoid copying the object instead pushing the raw pointer into an array?

Comment: Don't you mean `barInst.test = 2`? `bar` is a constructor, not an object. That is `foo[0]` does not equal `bar`...

Comment: Oh, sorry. Yes, I meant barInst.test instead of bar.test

Comment: In which case, your code should work. Does it? see: http://jsfiddle.net/p6LQh/

Comment: Oh.. Yeah it works.. And also I take a look into original sources and found an error and this is not a problem anymore. Both of code snippets (original and davin's code) are working. Thanks a lot for assistance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JS is pass-by-value, so your original assignment was `this.test = the value of 1`, in my example, it's `this.test = the object pointed to by ptr`, so when I change `ptr` `this.test` changes as well.

```
var foo = [],
    ptr = {val: 1},
    bar = function(){ 
       this.test = ptr;
       foo.push(this); // push an object (or a copy of object?) but not pointer
    },
    barInst = new bar(); // create new instance
    // foo[0].test.val equals 1
    ptr.val = 2;
    // foo[0].test.val equals 2
```

Although if you thought that `foo.push(this);` was similar, it isn't. Since this is an object, the array will indeed contain "raw pointers" to objects, just like you want. You can prove this simply:

```
foo[0].test = 3;
// barInst.test === 3
```

Which shows that it is indeed a pointer to the object that was pushed onto the array

Answer (score 0):

"create object method **pointer**"

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype,'pointer',{
    value:function(arr, val){
       return eval(
                  "this['"+arr.join("']['")+"']"+
                   ((val!==undefined)?("="+JSON.stringify(val)):"")
                  );
     }
});
```

ex of use

```
var o={a:1,b:{b1:2,b2:3},c:[1,2,3]}, arr=['b','b2']
o.pointer(arr)  // value 3
o.pointer(['c',0], "new_value" )
```

Comment: could rise problems not  escaped  '